# Azure CosmosDB Unexpected Pagination Behaviour

Tags: pagination, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are using CosmosDb C# SDK
We tried both: "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.4.1", "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 2.9.1 and 2.4.2"
We are getting invalid results and the main problems is the ResponseContinuation

> [{"token":null,"range":{"min":"05C1DFFFFFFFFC","max":"FF"}}]

This started showing in one of our smaller service with only 14 documents.

In all queryes we use the folowing headers:

- "x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition" = true
- "x-ms-max-item-count" = 100

**Query 1:**
The query is the folowing `SELECT * FROM c`.
We get the folowing response:
 - 7 items
 - ResponseContinuation `[{"token":null,"range":{"min":"05C1DFFFFFFFFC","max":"FF"}}]`

Then we use the continuation token to get the other 7 items.

**Query 2:**

If we modify the query to `SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c.property ASC`, the order gets messed up! (responses are simplified)
- we get the folowing result ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]
- and the second query ["C", "D", "G"]

**Query 3:**
if we want to find only one item `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM c WHERE c.name = @name`, and the item is in the "second query result"
- nothing and RequestContionuation `{"top":1,"sourceToken":"[{\"token\":null,\"range\":{\"min\":\"05C1DFFFFFFFFC\",\"max\":\"FF\"}}]"}`

This is all a really unexpected behaviour.
Why does ORDER BY, TOP even exist if we can't even use it properly..
We can't afford to list all data from cosmos to our server and then do ordering, expecialy on bigger containers.

Edit: github issue link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1001

Comment: I think we have the same problem. Server-side paging with ordering is not working properly when documents are across multiple partitions. EnableCrossPartitionQuery is enabled, but it seems we get a list of documents from first partition – e.g. first 5 ordered by property X and in the second partition there are documents which should be in response based on ordering by property X). We cannot load all documents and then do sorting and paging on the client side with 100k+ documents. As we have this in production your help would be very appreciated.